# Highcharts JS showing wrong colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a heatmap with values from -2 to 10.

I want:

-2 to be red
0 to be white
10 to be green

I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/m5xfx0wa/1/ but seems to not be working.

```
colorAxis: {

            stops: [
                [-2, '#ff0000'],
                [0, '#ffffff'],
                [10, '#00ff00']
            ],
            min: -2,
            max: 10
        },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between the scale and the range. In your case, the scale used in stops is between 0 and 1 and your range is defined by the min and max.
So you should do something like:

```
stops: [
                [0, '#ff0000'],
                [0.2, '#ffffff'],
                [1, '#00ff00']
            ],
```